# How to convert Panda's columns into an index and a header when index column has duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I’d like to convert a dataframe, df, similar to this one:

```
PIDM            | COURSE          | GRADE
1               | MAT1            | B
1               | PHY2            | C
2               | MAT1            | A
2               | MAT2            | B
2               | PHE2            | A
```

to the following format:

```
PIDM     |  MAT1      | PHY2    |  MAT2  | PHY 2  
1        |    B       |    C    |  NaN   |   NaN
2        |    A       |    NaN  |  B     |   A
```

I was assuming I could do something like:

```
df2 = df.pivot(index='PIDM', columns=‘COURSE’, values = ‘GRADE)
```

but I receive an error stating that I have duplicate indices.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with aggregate function `join`:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index='PIDM', columns='COURSE', values = 'GRADE', aggfunc=', '.join)
print (df2)
COURSE MAT1  MAT2  PHE2  PHY2
PIDM                         
1         B  None  None     C
2         A     B     A  None
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael! I have to wait 10m until I can accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Glad can help you.